# Spring MVC with Soap Service Multi Threading & Multi Server

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, thread-safety

I'm trying to create a small Sping MVC application that has concurrency. *Scenario*:

1: I am using ***WAS Websphere Server with 4 nodes*** with a ***Load Balancer***

2: I have 2 Modules : (a)Web Module (b) Service Module with Soap Web Service

3: Web Layer will call the Service Layer with the WebServiceTemplate.

4: The Service Layer has some business logic such as: calculating Total Amount being Deposited, Withdrawn etc.

Approaches I used:

1: I used ***synchronized*** in the Business logic methods *"Deposit, Withdraw"* etc - It Didn't work

2: I have not used any  ***Scope*** in the @Controller(I know this is Singleton)

Question:

Do I really need to change the Scope of the @Controller to "Request"?

My assumption: If I change the scope to *Request*, won't it make the application slower? For example, even just to get records(No change request), it will slow down

*What are the approaches we can use to make the only part of the code - "Withdraw" or "Deposit" Thread Safe in the Service Module?*

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 nodes that means your application is deployed 4 times. So using a local synchronization like the `synchronized` keyword will make only the threads from that instance synchronized on critical section access.

You must use something that controls the synchronization from outside. I have used Redis with Redisson library on Java for that.

1. Install a Redis instance
2. Add Redisson as a dependency on your project
3. Initialize RedissonClient class
4. When accessing the critical section (which is `Withdraw` or `Deposit`) you acquire a lock using the RedissonClient and release after the operation is finished.

By doing that the synchronization information will be held on Redis and all instances will share it which will not allow any to enter the critical section.

As you have two critical sections: `Withdraw` and `Deposit` you must use those (or other) names when acquiring the lock.

Comment: Thanks ! This is a great advise. 1 more question. Do we have to change the "Scope" of the @Controller to "Request" or not?

Comment: @greencheese No. the `@Controller` should always be a singleton, it is the bean that processes all requests. If you need something from a specific request then, down the chain, you can use a `@Request` bean. https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3750